# Type as property resolves as null with graphql-yoga and prisma

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I’m using a prisma server and graphql-yoga (graphql server on top of node.js) and I’m working for the first time with a type that has an other type as property. It’s one way so no relation I believe. In my case, a `Product` can be in a `FavoriteList` (so belong?) but a `FavoriteList` doesn’t have a relation the other way around.

```
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  releaseDate: DateTime!
  brand: Brand!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  image: Image!
  barcode: String
}

type FavoriteList {
  id: ID!
  products: [Product]
}
```

On my prisma admin I can add a record to `FavoriteList` with connecting `[Product]` and in the playground I can query for that by using the `FavoriteLists` query. But when I create a query (and resolver) for my graphql-yoga server, products are resolving as null. The query I’m using:

```
# prisma server & graphql server
query favoriteList {
  favoriteLists {
    id
    products {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}

My setup for the graphql-server
```

```
type Query {
  // ... other queries
  favoriteLists: [FavoriteList]
}

// resovler in Query.js
async favoriteLists(root, args, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.favoriteLists({}, info)
},
```

So having the same query, I am wondering if I have to do something else in my graphql-server? From what I can see the `Product` is not resolving on the `FavoriteList` type. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would disagree and say you should have a relationship between Product and FavouriteList. When you break it down, one Product "belongs to" one or many FavouriteList and one FavouriteList "has" many Product. So I'd define your datamodel like this:

```
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  releaseDate: DateTime!
  brand: Brand!
  createdAt: DateTime!
  image: Image!
  barcode: String
  favouriteLists: [FavouriteList!]! @relation(name: "ProductToFavouriteList")

}

type FavoriteList {
  id: ID!
  products: [Product!]! @relation(name: "ProductToFavouriteList")
}
```

Your query and resolvers look ok except maybe your resolver should return `context.prisma.query.favoriteLists({}, info)`?